# Non-numerical values errors as NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration

Here is my code: 
1. Define a Gaussian Mixture Model

```
SuperModel[w1_?NumericQ, w2_?NumericQ, w3_?NumericQ, w4_?NumericQ, 
  w5_?NumericQ, m1_?NumericQ, m2_?NumericQ, m3_?NumericQ, 
  m4_?NumericQ, m5_?NumericQ, m6_?NumericQ, m7_?NumericQ, 
  m8_?NumericQ, m9_?NumericQ, m10_?NumericQ, sigma1_?NumericQ, 
  sigma2_?NumericQ, sigma3_?NumericQ, sigma4_?NumericQ, 
  sigma5_?NumericQ] = 
 MixtureDistribution[{w1, w2, w3, w4, 
   w5}, {MultinormalDistribution[{m1, m2}, 
    IdentityMatrix[2]* sigma1], 
   MultinormalDistribution[{m3, m4}, IdentityMatrix[2]*sigma2], 
   MultinormalDistribution[{m5, m6}, IdentityMatrix[2]*sigma3], 
   MultinormalDistribution[{m7, m8}, IdentityMatrix[2]*sigma4], 
   MultinormalDistribution[{m9, m10}, IdentityMatrix[2]*sigma5]}]
```

2. Integral over the product of the PDF 
   [image]

```
NIntegrate[
 Product[PDF[
   SuperModel[w1, w2, w3, w4, 1 - (w1 + w2 + w3 + w4), m1, m2, m3, m4,
     m5, sigma1, sigma2, sigma3, sigma4, sigma5], 
   Part[ListY, j]], {j, n}], {m1, -1, 1}, {m2, -1, 1},  {m3, -1, 
  1}, {m4, -1, 1}, {m5, -1, 1}, {sigma1, 4, 16}, {sigma2, 4, 
  16}, {sigma3, 4, 16}, {sigma4, 4, 16}, {sigma5, 4, 
  16}, {w1, w2, w3, w4} \[Element] 
  RegionIntersection[
   ImplicitRegion[w1 + w2 + w3 + w4 <= 1, {w1, w2, w3, w4}],  
   ImplicitRegion[w1 >= 0, {w1, w2, w3, w4}], 
   ImplicitRegion[w2 >= 0, {w1, w2, w3, w4}], 
   ImplicitRegion[w3 >= 0, {w1, w2, w3, w4}], 
   ImplicitRegion[w4 >= 0, {w1, w2, w3, w4}]]]
```

Then it gives me following error code:
[image]
I'm curious what's wrong with the part of product of PDF?

Supplementary:

1. ListY: the list of $\{Y_i\}$, contain $n$ $Y_i$ generated from a specific Gaussian Mixture Model. For instance, let $n = 5$, then ListY could be:

```
{{0.574953, -3.92776}, {1.15219, -2.60178}, {-0.851673, -2.08292}, 
{-5.36409, 0.645265}, {0.560418, 3.89104}}
```

2. If I replace Product[...] with only a real number, it works:

```
NIntegrate[1, {m1, -1, 1}, {m2, -1, 1},  {m3, -1, 1}, {m4, -1, 
  1}, {m5, -1, 1}, {sigma1, 4, 16}, {sigma2, 4, 16}, {sigma3, 4, 
  16}, {sigma4, 4, 16}, {sigma5, 4, 16}, {w1, w2, w3, w4} \[Element] 
  RegionIntersection[
   ImplicitRegion[w1 + w2 + w3 + w4 <= 1, {w1, w2, w3, w4}],  
   ImplicitRegion[w1 >= 0, {w1, w2, w3, w4}], 
   ImplicitRegion[w2 >= 0, {w1, w2, w3, w4}], 
   ImplicitRegion[w3 >= 0, {w1, w2, w3, w4}], 
   ImplicitRegion[w4 >= 0, {w1, w2, w3, w4}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: What happens when you evaluate the integrand at a point in the domain? Do you get a number?

Comment: What is ListY?.

Comment: Seems I found one of the mistake in my codes....